# Speed of RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, performance

I have a site that is roughly one half "my" site, and one half a SAS site from a third party.

We've been trying to tackle a single sign on method for many moons.

It dawned on me recently that if I did some URL rewriting to display the third party site, but appear on our domain, the third party cookies would be written as coming from my site, and nullify any cross site scripting issues.

Is there any performance hit that I should be cautious about here? I use rewriting all over the place to hide file extensions and that sort of thing, and the end user does not notice a difference. Should I expect similar performance running an entire site/app through a proxy?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly do you think of doing with mod_rewrite here?

Comment: Rewrite my.site.com to 3rdparty.com, then utilize the cookie written from 3rdparty.com on my.site.com